# how to generate id for custom helpers in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This is how I tried to create custom HTML helper and generate an id to it
but when I use the tag in my razor, I'm getting the same id for all tags when rendered, some one help me to find solution.

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyLabel(this HtmlHelper html, string text)
        {
            var builder = new TagBuilder("myLable");

            builder.GenerateId("MyLableId1");

            builder.SetInnerText(text);
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
        }
```

In Razor

```
@using MvcAppCustomeHtmlHelpers.Helper;
@Html.MyLabel("username")
@Html.TextBox("username")<br/>
@Html.MyLabel("password")
@Html.TextBox("password")
```

when I render  text box the id is username and password for other textbox , but I'm unable to get id like text box for my custome html helper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass one more parameter "id".

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyLabel(this HtmlHelper html, string text, string id)
{
    var builder = new TagBuilder("myLable"); 
    builder.GenerateId(id);    
    builder.SetInnerText(text);
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
}
```

Now, you can use:

```
@Html.MyLabel("username", "label1") 
@Html.MyLabel("username", "label2")
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `TagBuilder.GenerateId`:

```
builder.GenerateId(text);
```

To be honest, this is nothing that a quick Google couldn't have told you:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/using-the-tagbuilder-class-to-build-html-helpers-cs